# Unable to locate WAMP servrer via localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, server, wamp

I have a problem with WAMP server vith Apache v.2.4.9. After complete reinstall of Win7 wamp server is unable to reach via localhost or 127.0.0.1, it shows error Not Found - The requested URL / was not found on this server. But (and that is interesting) its possible to get PHPmyadmin via http://localhost/phpmyadmin normally.

I tried all stuff I found - juggling with httpd.conf rights, with virtuals, on C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc I checked line with 127.0.0.1 localhost and I have no such program as Skype or other server witch is potencional blocker of port 80.

Only thing helps is set in httpd.conf listening on port 8080, but then I can get only root page (not sub directories) and it's unable to reach the database.

I'm stuck for developig home, so if you have any suggestion, please write to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably simply because the browser is using IPV6 sometimes and IPV4 at other times. Not sure what controls why the browser uses ipv4 or ipv6 but if you have ipv6 activated ( and w7 does ) it seems to make arbitrary decisions and can use either or both.

So you need to add the IPV6 loopback address to the HOSTS file.

Change the HOSTS file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` like so

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

A simple test would be to use this url in the browser instead of localhost

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

and if that runs the WAMPServer homepage then the above change will sort you out.

Comment: Thx for fast response, but I added ipv6 address and it didn't help